# Php : Get a record Function but Error : Undefined property

Tags: php

I have this problem when i try to build my function ! I need to build a function to get a record in database! And my error is Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$fetch_assoc in database.php

```
function db_get_row($sql){
    db_connect(); // Connect to Database
    global $connect; // Get Global Variable
    $row = array(); // Create array
    $result = $connect->query($sql); // Excute the query and return a record
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ // If record > 0 -> TRUE
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc; // I get that record into $row      HERE IS MY ERROR   
    }
    return $row; // Return array
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: missing ( ) to tell php it is a function

Comment: yes, but fetch_assoc looks like a function / method to fetch rows from your resultset

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @IvoP  sorry my mistake.you are right. I am thinking about `num_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on :- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc;
```

Need to be

```
$row[] = $result->fetch_assoc(); //it's a function and you are assigning to array
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have fixed it :P

Comment: Where i need to accept the answer ? i'm just starting to use stackoverflow , please help me . Thanks!

Comment: @Neko glad to help you

Comment: I have ticked it